# Show this IVP is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

I need to show that the IVP $y'=t^3, y(0)=0$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$. I know I need to find some number $L$ so that $\forall y_1, y_2$ and $t\in[a,b]$, $|f(t,y_2)-f(t,y_1)|\leq L|y_2-y_1|$.

I'm not quite sure what to do with this function since there is no $y$. This is what I'm thinking so far:
$|y_2^3-y_1^3|=|y_2-y_1|\cdot|y_2^2+y_1y_2+y_1^2|$. Technically we can bound $|y_2^2+y_1y_2+y_1^2|$ by some unknown real constant $M$, but I feel that's cheap with a lack of mathematical justification.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Since your equation doesn't have $y$, the Lipschitz condition holds automatically.

Comment: Sweet, would I just note this as $L=1$?

Comment: Since $f(t,y)=0$, so $|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|=0<L|y_1-y_2|$ and hence $L>0$ can be any number. $L=1$ is ok.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I haven't taken any differential equation courses, and this exercise is from a numerical analysis course. ^^